# HTML – a font displays correctly even if it's not installed?

Tags: fonts, website, html

I just visited a blog of someone I know (at http://istoletheinternet.blogspot.com/) and the header font in "Pen to Pillow" is displayed correctly, as far as I can tell ... My FireBug addon tells me the font is "Reenie Beanie" but I haven't got it on my computer and have never seen it before ... how does this work?

Can I also make HTML pages, give them to friends as a ZIP file and use fonts they don't have, and they will still display correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS allows for alien fonts to be imported by using `@font-face`. Another example would be http://askubuntu.com which uses the "Ubuntu" font.

Look [here](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680) and [here](http://www.zenelements.com/blog/css3-embed-font-face/) for some more explanations about how it's done exactly.

Answer (score 1):

That site you mentioned is using the Google WebFonts AJAX API.

http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like a web font. I've only dabbled in HTML on adobe Muse but Web Fonts are a sort of universal font that loads on every computer. It's generally something that you want to try to include in your site because like you said, you might not have that font installed. Sorry if any of this is wrong. Like I said, just a dabbeler passing through.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  How does he solve his problem precisely?

Comment: "My FireBug addon tells me the font is "Reenie Beanie" but I haven't got it on my computer and have never seen it before ... how does this work?"




My answer explains at least why he is able to view the font "Reenie Beenie" without having to install it on his or her computer. I know I've already said I'm a bit new but was the downvote necessary? I gave the same correct answer as Majenko above me and even gave an explanation.

Comment: I am not going to bother trying to defend my position.  You won't agree with anything I say.  I only vote on the content you submit, I could careless, who submits it.

Comment: That's fair. I just want to say that I don't disagree with everything people say. I do see where you would get that impression, I was just curious.